# C++ celsius to fahrenheit 3 times

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++, and to do that I have created myself a problem which is to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit three times in  the console. The user will input the Celsius degree. 
I also want the output to be displayed like this:

`Celsius:  Fahrenheit:
 cel1      fahr1 
 cel2      fahr2 
 cel3      fahr3`

The code I have tried so far is:

```
double cel1, cel2, cel3;
double fahr1, fahr2, fahr3;

cout << "Celsius degree one: ";
cin >> cel1;

cout << "Celsius degree two: ";
cin >> cel2;

cout << "Celsius degree three: ";
cin >> cel3;

fahr1 = (cel1 * 9) / 5 + 32;
fahr2 = (cel2 * 9) / 5 + 32;
fahr3 = (cel3 * 9) / 5 + 32;

// messy like this to display like I want to 
cout << endl <<
    "Celsius:  " << "Fahrenheit:" << endl <<
    cel1 << "         " << fahr1 << endl <<
    cel2 << "         " << fahr2 << endl <<
    cel3 << "         " << fahr3 << endl << endl;
```

which will display like I want to, but I feel this could have been achieved in  a simpler way, so I tried something like this with a loop, but I couldn't figure out how to do it properly:

```
double celsius;

for (int times = 0; times != 3; ++times){

    cout << "Celsius degree: ";
    cin >> celsius;

    double fahrenheit = (celsius * 9) / 5 + 32;

    cout << "Fahrenheit degree: " << fahrenheit << endl;

    cin.clear();

}
```

This code is less then the previous one, gives the correct answer and will convert three times, but I couldn't figure out how to display it like I want to.

My question is what is the best way to do this?

Comment: you'd have to rewrite your loop and SAVE all three input values, THEN do your output. Right now you're getting `cfcfcf` for output, when you should be doing `cccfff`

Comment: You have to use some array: `double celsius[3]` or `std::array<double, 3> celius;` or `std::vector<double> celsius(3);`.

Comment: Use `double` math: `fahr1 = (cel1 * 9.0) / 5.0 + 32.0;`

Comment: You may also wrap your conversion into a function `double celsius_to_fahrenheit(double celsius) { return (celsius * 9.0) / 5.0 + 32.0; }`

Comment: @MarcB yes, but I dont really know how to store the input values until I can tell it to output to after the third time. Could this be done with something Jarod42 is mentioning, if so how?

Comment: @Jarod42 oh sweet. Didn't know that I could wrap that into a function.

Comment: @Rockyy: I let you search a little, I will you show a solution tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create arrays to store the temperatues.

   Instead of

   ```
   double cel1, cel2, cel3;
   double fahr1, fahr2, fahr3;
   ```

use

```
    double celsius[3];
    double fahrenheit[3];
```

1. Change the input gathering loop to use the arrays.

   ```
   for (int times = 0; times != 3; ++times){

       cout << "Celsius degree: ";
       cin >> celsius[times];

       fahrenheit[times] = (celsius[times] * 9) / 5 + 32;

       cin.clear();
   }
   ```
2. Use a loop to create the output:

   ```
   cout << endl << "Celsius:  " << "Fahrenheit:" << endl <<
   for (int times = 0; times != 3; ++times){
     cout << celsius[times] << "         " << fahrenheit[times] << endl;
   }
   ```

You could get away with not creating the array `fahrenheit` too if you compute it only during output.

In that case, change the input gathering loop to:

```
    for (int times = 0; times != 3; ++times){

        cout << "Celsius degree: ";
        cin >> celsius[times];

        cin.clear();
    }
```

Change the output loop to:

```
    cout << endl << "Celsius:  " << "Fahrenheit:" << endl <<
    for (int times = 0; times != 3; ++times){
      double fahrenheit = (celsius[times] * 9) / 5 + 32;
      cout << celsius[times] << "         " << fahrenheit << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Very annoyed with myself that I couldn't see this from my first code sample, but I  think I had a little problem understanding how I should arrays and therefore had trouble using loops. Or if I should use arrays or vectors. This made it all clear for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to split the code into smaller functions:

The one to compute the conversion

```
double celsius_to_fahrenheit(double celsius)
{
    return (celsius * 9.0) / 5.0 + 32.0;
}
```

The one to get the input, I choose to use `std::vector` as container.
you may choose `std::array<double, 3>` since the array have fixed size,
but `std::vector` is a good default choice.

```
std::vector<double> get_input_celsius(std::size_t size)
{
    std::vector<double> celsius(size);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != celsius.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "Celsius degree " << (i + 1) << ": ";
        std::cin >> celsius[i];
    }
    return celsius;
}
```

The method to display the result. I choose to not store the conversion in a new `std::vector` since it is not used afterward:

```
void display_celsius_and_fahrenheit(const std::vector<double>& celsius)
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "Celsius:  " << "Fahrenheit:" << std::endl;
    for (auto c : celsius) { // for range since C++11
        std::cout << c << "         " << celsius_to_fahrenheit(c) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And finally the `main` function:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<double> celsius = get_input_celsius(3);

    display_celsius_and_fahrenheit(celsius);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/xtFYzK)